# Axis2 on server with different clients

Tags: client-server, apache-axis

Is it possible to run axis2 on the server and the clients sending the soap messages not use axis?  This uses an in-out process. If so, have you seen any issues from doing this?

Comment: If you're looking for more information suggest you update your question with more specific details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The whole idea behind web services is interoperability.

There can be issues.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do so it's hard to say what those issues would be.